# getting an AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

after installing speedtest module, getting an AttributeError[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OOI.png)

going to create internet speed checker, but stuck on this error in the first place

Comment: Recommendation for posting questions here - get familiar with Markdown syntax. That will allow you to post your code directly into the question rather than providing a link to a picture of it. You are already using Markdown in your Jupyter notebooks, so it'll be an easy learning curve for you. To learn more check out the [Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not called the function, only referenced it. Add the brackets after Speedtest.

```
st = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/test-internet-speed-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate a new object. Use `test = speedtest.Speedtest()` instead.